# How to sandbox Jest tests

Tags: node.js, jestjs

According to Jest docs:

"Sandboxed test files and automatic global state resets for every test so **no two tests conflict with each other**."

However my tests conflict.

Code:

```
// Note: op is from object-path module for deep access by dot path
let config = { name: 'Bob' }

const getConfig = path => {
  return op.get(config, path) 
}

const setConfig = (path, value) => {
  return op.set(config, path, value)
}
```

Tests:

```
test('setConfig() updates a deep config value', () => {
  const { setConfig, getConfig } = require('services/config')

  setConfig('name', 'Woot')
  const res = getConfig('name')
  expect(res).toBe('Woot')
})

test('getConfig() updates a deep config value', () => {
  const { getConfig } = require('services/config')

  const res = getConfig('name')
  expect(res).toBe('Bob') // Actually Woot
})
```

The first test modifies the config file causing second test to fail.

From my experience things like `process.env` do not get sandboxed but this? What am I not understanding about "sandboxing"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like sandboxing in Jest only happens for files by default, and not for individual tests within the same file.

This is because Jest doesn't uncache the modules by default.

However it does provide a function, `jest.resetModules` that you to call before each test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules()
});
```

This will uncache your modules and enable sandboxing.
You can also [configure Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html) by setting `resetModules` in your `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "jest": {
    "resetModules": true
  }
}
```

To take advantage of these settings you need to `require` your modules in each test (which you are already doing). I'm just mentioning this because even if you called `jest.resetModules`, your tests would have failed if you had a single `require` at the top of the file.

Comment: I noticed one caveat of this is that even when added at the beginning of the beforeEach function it runs after the beforeEach thereby wiping/uncaching anything done in the beforeEach call. I ended up having to write my own code to clear what I needed.